# SQL count of values from different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a `Dog` table. Each dog has `Breed` and can have 0 to 2 photos. I need to recieve count of photos of all dogs for each breed: table with `BreedId` and matching `PhotosCount`. So result table should be:

```
BreedID|PhotosCount
-------------------
1      |3
-------------------
2      |1
-------------------
```

[image: Dogs]

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, with COUNT().

Comment: but where come from the columns B and C? Are they dog names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT BreedID AS B, COUNT(Photo1) + COUNT(Photo2) AS C
FROM Dog
GROUP BY BreedID
```

`COUNT` aggregate function simply doesn't take into consideration `NULL` values. If, for a specific `BreedID`, *all* values of either `Photo1` or `Photo2` are `NULL`, then `COUNT` returns `0`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in single scan:

```
SELECT
    BreedID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Photo1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    + SUM(CASE WHEN Photo2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Count]
FROM Table
GROUP BY BreedID
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **Group By** and **SUM** Of Photo1 and Photo2:

**Note:** If you wants the output for each dog you have to include DogId in group clause.

```
;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT          
        BreedId,
        SUM (CASE ISNULL(Photo1,0) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Photo1,
        SUM (CASE ISNULL(Photo2,0) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Photo2
    FROM TableName
    Group By BreedId
)
SELECT      
    BreedId,
    SUM(Photo1+Photo2) AS TotalPhoto
FROM T
```

**Or Simply**

```
SELECT        
    BreedId,
    SUM (CASE ISNULL(Photo1,0) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +  CASE ISNULL(Photo2,0) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalPhoto       
FROM TableName
Group By BreedId
```

Comment: yes, it's bad idea to use `COUNT` and `ISNULL` together. `NULL` values will be counted in this case

Comment: And `GROUP BY` two fields is also wrong :) You can just check the right answer above :)

Comment: OP has mention in requirement for each dog and breed but in example show only breedId, so i have include dog and write note for it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT BreedID AS Breed, COUNT(Photo1) + COUNT(Photo2) AS #ofPhotos
FROM Dog
GROUP BY BreedID;
```